# Dubai airport: what currency do taxi drivers accept going from T3 to T2

Tags: airport-transfer, dubai, dxb

From Birmingham (UK) to Dubai terminal 3

From Dubai to Ahwaz(Iran) terminal 2

Comment: You're taking a taxi to travel between terminals ? I remember reading on the Emirates website they provide a shuttle for this

Comment: I read that shuttles are available between T1 to T3 not from T3 to T2 ! I need to be sure about that!? Thank you.

Comment: You can walk between T1 and T3 at DXB, they're joined! There's an airside bus to/from T2

Comment: I knew I read that somewhere, it's [here](http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/connecting_with_flydubai.aspx) *At the Dubai International Airport, Emirates also connects you by coach, from arriving in Emirates Terminal 3 right through to your departing gates in Terminal 2*

Comment: Do you have a credit card?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are in the UAE, you'll have to pay in Dirhams, as that is the currency there.

According to a [couple](http://answers.worldnomads.com/questions/united-arab-emirates/11994/in-dubai-airport-taxi-accepts-euros-or-only-dirhams) of [answers](http://answers.worldnomads.com/questions/united-arab-emirates/19712/cost-of-taxi-from-dubai-airport-to-holiday-inn-and-what-currency-to-pay) I found on worldnomads, that's the case. There's an ATM and an exchange desk in the airport but it seems the taxis also accept credit cards.

Based on your previous question however, you should know there's a [free shuttle service](http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/connecting_with_flydubai.aspx) provided by Emirates for customers connecting to FlyDubai

> At the Dubai International Airport, Emirates also connects you by
>   coach, from arriving in Emirates Terminal 3 right through to your
>   departing gates in Terminal 2

Comment: However, the OP doesn't actually need to take a taxi in the first place, as there's a perfectly good + free airside transfer bus!

Comment: The fare is certainly quoted in AED, it is also quite tightly regulated so I don't know if USD or something else would be acceptable.

Comment: @Gagravarr that's right, and I gave him the link. But it doesn't really answer his question

Answer (score 0):

I used http://kiwitaxi.com/UAE/Dubai+Airport and it was possible to pay in dollars. But I know all services in UAE are paid exclusively in their national currency Dirhams.

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with the company?

Comment: I share my experience and that`s it.